# Validate $_POST variables for functions that use them

Tags: php, post

Many of my functions that take user data receive them via post rather than GET i.e. passing them in the url such as 'class/method/param1/param2'.

I want to know if it is a good idea to make a static function that is called first in a function that deals with POST data? i.e.:

```
public function myMethod()
{
    Util::validatePost();
}

...

public static function validatePost()
{
    foreach($_POST as $param => $value){
      // Do some validation stuff...
    }
}
...
```

An example rule would be that any POST variable with a key name containing 'id' must be a number and fails if it is anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many PHP Frameworks do that (Symfony2 is just an example).

They use some validation rules and input escaping facility, in order to validate user input, so, yes, don't trust everything user sends you but do all you can do to verify input.

Moreover, a static function (or many static functions) will be coupled with single (or many) forms. I suggest you to implement a specific function for every form (or general data) you need to verify

## Please, pay attention

Don't trust HTML5 or JavaScript constraints because they could be easily bypassed. As I suggest in comment, control user input at "the last step" (i.e. on bind data with model or form, or whatever)

Comment: @DonCallisto Thanks, I have made my own mini-framework and I'm still learning. I guess this would be better placed in the controller that all my classes extend from and is called from the __construct() method so it's invoked everytime?

Comment: @imperium2335: make a "bind" method that will do it for you. Leave constructor clean as possibile (remember that you can use constructor even to build blank and without-data forms) and make all controls at binding time. Obviously, you have to bind all data once you receive a post, but this could be leave to user logic

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that it is not a good idea, for a number of reasons, such as:

- It produces strong dependencies between code and room for errors and debugging pain.
- Especially php is tricky with type casts. Remeber that every post variable initially arrives as a String. Also
- The type of validation needed always depends on the usage. What if you suddenly have string ids somewhere?

Of course there are some validations that can take place. PHP module suhosin (AKA hardened php) for exmaple does it to prevent attacks.

However in my experience it is a good practice to clean user data at the point where it is processed.

For example I ALWAYS apply quoting to data I use in a database query. Alawys, right before the query is constructed.

I never rely on the data to be safe in the first place.

You also should never trust any data provided by external sources in any case.

Alwas validate it right for what you do it when you do it and you will be fine.

Comment: I always use PDO prepare (non-emulated) at the point where it goes into my database anyway, but I am wondering if this is enough on its own?

Comment: yes, it is. you can also use the pdo quote function. better do it at one point properly than to rely on a series of potentially weak ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a bad idea. Although this might work very well at first it requires you to be very strict with this all time, and from expierence I've learned that you will always end up with variables that must be numeric, but not with ID field naming.

Also you probably need much more validation (like valid phonenumber, emailaddress, zipcode or perhaps a valid guid).

In the end you still need to validate each param before you can anything with it, so this seems useless.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea. More in general you can't trust anything coming from the client so it's always a good idea to check/validate it.

I would recommend you to use some PHP library to handle HTTP requests in an easy way. Try this Symfony component, for instance:
https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel